# Saving changes of attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

I'm doing changes to a new field I created on the attribute table of a grid shapefile (.gpkg), the grid is circle clipped to the extent of a 4km radius buffer, it contains 499358 cells. The new field is  a short integer type and I'm assigning a number to each cell of the grid according to different types of land cover, for example, if I overlay this grid to a remote sensing image and select some cells that are 100% Forest land cover, I would put 1 in that new field, and if it is infrastructure I would put 2.

I edited the table, saved the edits and exported the grid as a .csv file but when I opened it, the new field column was completely empty and when I checked the attibute table directly on QGIS all the changes that I've donde are gone and the values are "NULL". Does anyone know what can I do about this? I'm using QGIS 3.10 long term release A Coruña

Comment: Can you explain, why you repost your question from this morning, instead of improving it?

Comment: I accidentally deleted it

Comment: Nice. Some people tend to repost questions when they don't get the answer they want to have within X hours, hence I am asking =) Can you add some information on the size of your grid (spatial and MB-wise), as well as your "assigning numbers" process?

Comment: Added the information to the question

Comment: And you're doing the editing manually?

Comment: Yes, I am. I tried saving the grid as a geopackage instead of a shapefile and it worked, I was able to modify the new field. However, when I exported the attribute table as .csv my new field column was completely empty but I saved all the edits.